# C# пространства имен

Tags: c#, namespace

Решение содержит следующую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классы Functions, FuzzyMath и другие из скриншота со структурой решения хочу использовать в проекте lab1. Эти классы определены в пространстве имен FuzzySets

В lab1 в program.cs пытаюсь подключить этот namespace, чтобы получить доступ к вышеописанным классам, но получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно получить доступ к классам из пространства имен FuzzySets ?

Comment: .net framework сборок сильно отличается? если у библиотеки выше, то не увидит её.

Comment: Ну так вы добавили ссылку на dll? [Manage references](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Никакого .dll нет!

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ссылку (*Reference*) на `FuzzySets.dll` или на `FuzzySets.csproj` в проект `lab1.csproj`.

Comment: ошибка при добавлении csproj-файла

Comment: @VanyaBelyaev Какая ошибка - не скажете?

Comment: Убедитесь, что файл доступен и является допустимой сборкой или компонентом СОМ